# PHP Youtube API v3 Missing Description in Playlist Items

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm not getting the description form my uploaded videos when i query them via Youtube Data API v3 using OAuth 2.0 and the sample code provided here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list.

Could this be a bug? None of my videos are private and the only thing that is missing from the response is the video's description!

I'm using the PHP library and the "part" parameter is snippet (don't know if this helps).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is intended, since video descriptions are not displayed when viewing playlists on YouTube.

If you wish to include the description of your uploaded videos, consider using [YouTube API v3 Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) instead. An ellipsis-truncated description will be provided for your videos under *snippet/description*. Again, this behaviour is similar to searching on YouTube, where descriptions are cut off.

If a full description is required, you'll need to use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).
Alternatively, use version 2 of the API: [https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/**youtube_username**/uploads?max-results=50&start-index=1](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/youtube_username/uploads?max-results=50&start-index=1).